# I would like to Repeat rows N times while updating specific columns in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
     A     B     C  D
0   100 Test1   C1  D1
1   200 Test2   C1  D1
2   300 Test3   C1  D1
3   400 Test4   C1  D1
4   500 Test5   C1  D1
```

I would like to repeat all rows, but at the same time change the values of columns "C" and "D"

Output DataFrame:

```
     A   B      C   D
0   100 Test1   C1  D1
1   200 Test2   C1  D1
2   300 Test3   C1  D1
3   400 Test4   C1  D1
4   500 Test5   C1  D1
5   100 Test1   C2  D2
6   200 Test2   C2  D2
7   300 Test3   C2  D2
8   400 Test4   C2  D2
9   500 Test5   C2  D2
```

Please can someone assist? I just can get this one....

Comment: `df.loc[:, ['C', 'D']] = ['C2', 'D2']`

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat` the dataframe and its modified self:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.assign(C='C2', D='D2')], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     A      B   C   D
0  100  Test1  C1  D1
1  200  Test2  C1  D1
2  300  Test3  C1  D1
3  400  Test4  C1  D1
4  500  Test5  C1  D1
5  100  Test1  C2  D2
6  200  Test2  C2  D2
7  300  Test3  C2  D2
8  400  Test4  C2  D2
9  500  Test5  C2  D2
```

If you have more complex column names (with spaces or special characters), prefer this syntax:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.assign(**{'C': 'C2', 'D': 'D2'})], ignore_index=True)
```